# SQL Server error catch when import Excel file

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql

I want to import an Excel file to SQL Server, and I want to create an error catch if something went wrong.

I have this code, but the "try - catch" is not working if the path to the file is wrong or the name of the sheet is wrong.

```
begin try
    insert into Tbl_Excel
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENROWSET(
        'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
        'Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;Database=C:\FTP_Folder\Data.xlsx',
        'select * from [Sheet1$]')
end try

begin catch
    select 'Error'
end catch
```

How can I catch an error if something went wrong ?

Comment: This is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#errors-unaffected-by-a-trycatch-construct) behaviour. *"The following types of errors are not handled by a CATCH block when they occur at the same level of execution as the TRY...CATCH construct:  Errors that occur during statement-level recompilation, such as object name resolution errors that occur after compilation because of deferred name resolution."* The object resolution will occur after compilation, so can't be caught by the `TRY...CATCH`.

Comment: You can use SQLCLR or XP_CMDShell to check if the file exists first and if it exists then execute the OPENROWSET query. If it does not exists then execute a query which return error